# How to label one point using geom_label in geom_point plot that follows color gradient of latter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` which has 3 real valued columns `a,b,c`, and a string column `d`. I'm creating a 2D plot where column c is color coded like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c)) +
geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2) +
geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype=2) +
geom_point(size=.5) +
geom_density2d(color="black", alpha=.5) +
scale_color_gradient2(name="col", low="#0000ff", mid="#f7f7f7", high="#a80000", breaks=c(-2, 0, +2))
```

Now I wanted to create a separate plot based on the above where I label just one point(using its index which I know), so I added a geom_label, and wanted the fill of the label box to have the appropriate color for that point(a row in the dataframe):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c)) +
geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2) +
geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype=2) +
geom_point(size=.5) +
geom_density2d(color="black", alpha=.5) +
scale_color_gradient2(name="col", low="#0000ff", mid="#f7f7f7", high="#a80000", breaks=c(-2, 0, +2)) +
geom_label(data=df['x'], aes=(x=a, y=b, fill=c, label=d), 
fontface="bold", show.legend=F, color="black")
```

However this doesn't work, as the color gradient does not apply to the label - it treats it like a separate dataframe(so that label just gets the lowest color). How do I get the label to obey the previous color gradient?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do: create separate column for labels and so can customize each point by passing its name to ggplot. Make it what you want for that point, and empty ""  for the rest